# how to create apps for winget via electron.js

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, electron-builder, winget

how to create apps for winget using electron.js, I first thought of using `portable` in target but it just installs the app but I can't use it again, is the any other `targets` which I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Today, you would need to be able to provide an installer for an electron.js app. The Windows Package Manager supports three types of installers as of the 1.1 release.

- MSIX
- MSI
- .exe installers

Work is in progress for portable applications (just a loose executable like NuGet), and for installers inside of a .zip file. These are targeted for the 1.3 release.